# Correct PHP Session and variable syntax

Tags: php, syntax

The following syntax is incorrect:

```
$_session['page'$numberpages]=$CurrentPage;
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
$_SESSION['page'.$numberpages] = $CurrentPage;
```

- [`$_SESSION`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) is a special [superglobal variable](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and needs to be in uppercase.
- `'page'.$numberpages` needs the [string concatenation operator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 11):

You're missing a dot, a concatenation dot:

```
$_SESSION['page' . $numberpages]=$CurrentPage;
```

Or use double quotes:

```
$_SESSION["page$numberpages"]=$CurrentPage;
```

And, variable names are case-sensitive in PHP, unlike function names. So, it should be `$_SESSION`, instead of `$_session`.

Answer (score 5):

```
 $_SESSION['page' . $numberpages] = $CurrentPage;
```